# Action Implementation in Spring Webflow 2

Tags: spring, action, implementation, spring-webflow

I'm trying to implement a SWF action like this:

```
@Component(value = "initializeProjectsTestingFormAction")
public class InitializeProjectsTestingFormAction implements Action {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectsBo projectsBo;

    @Override
    public Event execute(RequestContext requestContext) throws Exception {
        ProjectsTestingForm projectsTestingForm = (ProjectsTestingForm) requestContext.getFlowScope().get("projectsTestingForm");

        EndUse selectedEndUse = (EndUse) requestContext.getFlowScope().get("selectedEndUse");
        projectsTestingForm.setProjects(projectsBo.findImplementableProjectsForTesting(selectedEndUse));

        return new Event("", "initializeProjectsTestingFormAction");
    }
}
```

It currently works fine when the flow invokes the action, but I feel slightly unsettled about the Event that the action have to return. Does anybody knows what the Event is and what could affect to the flow behavior depending on its values (source and id)?

I was reading the documentation but I'm not able to understand at all and answer myself the question:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/index.html
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/Event.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` of the event (second parameter of the constructor) should correspond to the `on` attribute of the transition that should be taken after the action is invoked.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, that make sense. What about the first argument of the constructor,`source`? What's the utility of that argument and what affects to? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: It's a required constructor parameter for the generic Java superclass `java.util.EventObject`. Not sure what, if anything, it's used for in the context of webflow.

Comment: Great, I'll do some tests to find out something else. Do you have an example of a SWF Action implementation and its respective use in the flow? Just for contrasting with the way I'm doing it, my Action is working but I want to be 100% sure about the right use of Actions because I have to implement a bunch of them. Thanks.